# What nutrients directly increase the blood preassure when absorbed?

Tags: micronutrients, blood-pressure, macronutrient

If I understand [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6770596/) article correctly, the uptake of sodium from the gut into the blood stream directly increases the blood preassure, partly by retaining water in the blood stream.

What nutrients (fat, protein and carbohydrates, electrolytes, etc) directly increases blood preassure and how?

Comment: Wow. This is such a broad question that I can only suggest the OP enroll in medical school, or at least a nutritionist program. If we understood the broad answer to this question, then we might actually be able to control blood pressure - if the patient would listen to us :D . Then there's exercise, life-style, and genetics. Let me know when you have the answer, until then, listen to your doctor.

Comment: @zombiefeeder I hear you. I guess I'll have to Investigate nutrient by nutrient. Perhaps med-school is an option... ^_^